# Bootstrap href does not actually link

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with a link in a bootstrap page that I have inherited. I am trying to link to an external program when the user clicks on the link. The line in question is:

```
<a title="Log In" href="#" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>    
<a title="Go to Tools page" data-target="#" href="/tools.php">Tools</a></li>
```

This is part of the menu bar. When I click on the TOOLS link nothing happens. If I hover over it in the browser, I see the complete link.

I know very little about bootstrap and google wasn't my friend with this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Any JavaScript interfering with the link?

Comment: @DavidG That was my thought but I haven't found it yet. I suspect it's in the bootstrap.min.js file.

Comment: What is `data-target="#"` for? I guess Bootstrap is recognising this link as a tab header because of this. Remove it to confirm.

Comment: @TimRogers That was one of the few google suggestions I tried. Originally I did not have that.

Comment: It's likely some jQuery getting in the way then.

Comment: @DavidG I agree. However what? I'm sure someone with Bootstrap experience knows this as a basic item.

Comment: @mlewis54 I've got lots of Bootstrap experience and never seen this. Try removing the reference to your js files one by one and see at what point it starts working.

Comment: You'll need to post some of the surrounding HTML then, or step into Bootstrap with your debugger to see what is swallowing the click.

Comment: @DavidG didn't mean to imply you didn't have bootstrap experience. I was just pointing out that I didn't. I'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: @mlewis54 No worries, I didn't take it that way. If it's still happening after all your js files are removed, there must be jQuery embedded on the page.

Comment: @DavidG the culprit is jquery.singlePageNav.js. I delete that and the link works. Now I just have to find out why.

Comment: @mlewis54 https://github.com/jeroenweustink/single-page-nav

Comment: @DavidG Very odd, the problem was that singlePageNav was never being initialized (except for any inline code which was swallowing the click), just included. Turns out the page works fine without it so I deleted it and everything is working fine. Please put it in the form of an answer and I'll accept it (since you did find the solution). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Surely data-target="#"

Is the issue? If you remove that it should work.

Comment: See comment above, does not work whether there or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have some JavaScript in your solution somewhere that is causing the interference. It's either embedded in the page or referenced in an external `.js` file.

If it's external, remove the references one by one until the problem disappears and you will then know the cause.